# Expandable ListView scroll

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

Is it possible to scroll the parent layout radar than scrolling only the expandable ListView content?

I have googled it but unable to find suitable solution

Comment: The answer is here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861588/android-expandable-listview-automatically-scrolls-to-the-bottom-when-i-click-on?rq=1

Comment: I have applied the android:transcriptMode in expandable listView but I want the scrolling in the whole layout not in the particular View that has got the expandable ListView