# When the group is expending, automatically scrolls on to last child item

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an app with an `ExpandableListView`. When the child list is longer than the screen, the list is initially shown as scrolled to the bottom /image 1/. How can I make it expand to a list that opens to the beginning of the list instead of the end /image 2/.

It happens when the previous group was collapsing.

```
collapseGroup(previousGroup);
```

[image: This is how it currently works]
[image: This is how i need it to work]

[The answer on this similar post didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861588/android-expandable-listview-automatically-scrolls-to-the-bottom-when-i-click-on)

Comment: I also did it. expListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4U0e1CrgsXPNUVLMGlSU0Zhekk&usp=sharing

Comment: now.png is how working now, and nead.png what I nead

Comment: That is not normal behaviour. Normal is that the group header stays visible when it's childs expand. That's what is happening here. I do not understand what this has to do with a previous group that was collapsing. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: For example the second group was expended, which has 5 child item. Now I am clicking the forth group to expend, which has 9 child item. When the forth group was expending the second group was collapsing, after I have this view https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4U0e1CrgsXPeURmLTN1WHhDVWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: But when all groups are collapsed, the forth group which has 9 item, is expending normal.

Answer (score 1):

Call something like this on expend group

For a direct scroll:

```
getListView().setSelection(childPosition);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(childPosition);
```